# How does one apply a one way decrease in opacity along a curved line geometry in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I've tried making replacing the material with an image of a gradient but that did not work, I've also looked into vertex shaders but those seemed to use inputs from the scene while rendering to change the color where as I just want one constant effect.

I also tried seeing if I could manually set an opacity for each point on the curve but there didn't seem to be a way to do that either.

Here's the section of code that make the ellipses, don't mind some of the specific variables in use, it's part of a project I've been working on for a while.

```
        var curve = new THREE.EllipseCurve(
            foci(1000 * earth_barycenter.Data[9] * base.a, semiminor(1000 * earth_barycenter.Data[9] * base.a, base.e)), 0,            // where the middle is
            1000 * earth_barycenter.Data[9] * base.a, semiminor(1000 * earth_barycenter.Data[9] * base.a, base.e),           // xRadius, yRadius
            0, 2 * Math.PI,  // aStartAngle, aEndAngle
            false,            // aClockwise
            0                 // aRotation
        );
        var material = color
        var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(curve.getPoints(points))
        var orbit = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
        scene.add(orbit);
```

The effect I'm going for is pretty much this: [image: space engine screenshot]

And this is what I currently have: [image: my project]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, I can describe how I see this working using the fragment shader.

You are right that shaders need input from the scene to animate, you can input **time** to make it consistently animate without worrying about user input. After you add time as uniform to your material, you can have a global or something called time, set it to zero, then in your update or animate function you can:

```
    time += 0.001;
    material.uniforms.time.value = time;
```

Then the rings are full meshes with no moving parts, like just like a basic ring, then in the fragment shader you pass in time and you just assign the output color like this:

```
vec4 color = vec4(1, 1, 1, mod(uv.x+time,1.0)); // the alpha value is the last one
```

then you just have to make sure the the UVs on your ring are set up that x axis is along the parameter and the y axis is the radius. I am not sure how three.js lays out the UVs for the line mesh, but you can make something like this in a 3d modeling software and set the UVs yourself. This might be too much of a pain if you aren't familiar with 3d modeling.
If this seems like too much for right now, I'd suggest using a gradient texture upon the 3d model, and rotating it. Maybe update your question with what went wrong when you tried that.
In working with three.js I always advise not shying away from getting 3d models from elsewhere and loading them in, for me, it usually is a faster way to get the desired effect.

Comment: cool! hopefully the uv can be set how you like it by updating the attribute in the line geometry.

Comment: so how do i get it to apply the vec4 to each vertex in sequence? from my understanding of shaders they effect all vertices with the same function.

Comment: thats where the uv comes in! This examples is not a vertex shader, so its not per vertex, its per location on the mesh as a whole.

Comment: This is for a fragment shader. it will work in a vertex shader if you can figure out a way to get vertexID in the vertex shader you can have it affect the vertices differently using the vertexID (which should be increasing in order, hopefully)